# Floating divs don't expand body width

Tags: css, html, document-body

I'm trying to develop a horizontal web page, with fixed height and variable width.

In order to get it, I need a row of floating `<div>`s to expand the `<body>` width.

```
|------------- body --------------|   /* variable width */
  |-div-| |-div-| |-div-| |-div-|     /*  fixed width   */
```

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
body{
  height: 40px;
}

div{
    width: 2000px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7cS2R/12/

Is is possible to do so without using javascript?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

Block elements expand to the full width of their parent-element's width. To make them respect their childrens with you can either declare:

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
position:absolute;
```

on your body-element.

EDIT: after you clarified your question - simply add the `white-space` declaration to your body:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/7cS2R/13/)**

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear at all. What I really wanted was `div`s to expand the `body` width by keeping the 'float: left' property.

I'll try to rewrite it to make it more accurate.

Comment: @EduPoch as i said, this depends on the boxmodel of the body-element, not on whether the child-divs are floated or not. You need to modify the body-element so that the divs can actually expand it's width.

Comment: That doesn't work for me either. `<div>`s are vertically stacked. What I really want is to maintain the horizontal stack that we can get with `float: left`.

Comment: @EduPoch aaaaaaaaah, why didn't you say that in the first place? I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well... It actually doesn't work on Firefox nor on IE. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7cS2R/6/